# Store Html type in postgresql result in 'bytes'

Tags: postgresql, haskell, yesod

With yesod-0.10.1

Definition:

```
postBlogR :: Handler RepHtml
postBlogR = do
    ((res, articleWidget), enctype) <- runFormPost entryForm
    case res of
        FormSuccess article -> do
            articleId <- runDB $ insert article
            setMessage $ toHtml $ (articleTitle article) <> " created"
            redirect $ ArticleR articleId
        _ -> defaultLayout $ do
                setTitle "Please correct your entry form"
                $(widgetFile "articleAddError")
```

Database

```
Article
    title Text
    content Html
    deriving
```

I get `\x48656c6c6f2c20776f726c6421` in database if I post `Hello, world!`

Comment: that is a representation of the bytes that means Hello, world!. The issue is only a representation issue. you'll probably want to store html as TEXT, rather that as BLOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue came up on the mailing list (is the question coming from the same person?). Anyway, the answer is here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/yesodweb/VMGqhS1QAsk/discussion

Comment: I'd believe that the "wl" in *chenwl* would stand for *wenlong* :).  I'd also believe that the Michael Snoyman here is the same Michael Snoyman there ;)